# Why do I get an "Operation not permitted" error when running duplicity as sudo?

Tags: backup, chown, duplicity

Currently I'm backing up my `/home/` folder to a usb mounted on `/media/liamzebedee/X` using **duplicity**. When I go to restore the folder to the USB however (using sudo), I get the error -

> Error '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/media/liamzebedee/X/home'' processing .

The files are all restored, why do I get this error?

Comment: Also, see the Launchpad bug on this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/415619

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I receive this error because **duplicity** cannot *chown* the restored home folder `/media/liamzebedee/X/home` to its original owner root. When restoring to `/` this works.

Answer (score 1):

whats the filesystem of your usb drive?

the error occures generally when resetting the permissons/ownership of the restored file fails. this can have many reasons. e.g.

1. target filesystem does not support these
2. you are not root, only root can set ownership

.. ede